# Remove warning viewPagerAndroid with react native 0.59.5

Tags: react-native

After upgrading to `react native 0.59.5`, the app threw the following warning message on simulator:

```
viewPagerAndroid has been extracted from react-native core...
```

But there is no import of the `viewPagerAndroid` in the component file:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { SectionList, View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Platform, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Moment from 'moment';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
```

How to remove the warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of react-native `0.59.0` ViewPagerAndroid has been deprecated. You can see that in the changelog [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecated).

That means that if you want to use ViewPagerAndroid in the future you will need to install it separately. You can see its repo [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager/blob/master/README.md)

You are probably seeing this warning even though you haven’t explicitly used ViewPagerAndroid because one of the dependencies that you are using used it.

Most commonly [react-native-gesture-handler](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/482) or [react-native-tab-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/issues/682) both use ViewPagerHandler.

At the moment the warning is just that, a warning. It isn’t going to cause you any issues until support for ViewPagerAndroid is dropped.

You can suppress the YellowBox warning so it won’t show on device. **Note** even if you suppress the warning it will **always** show in the logs.

Import it from react-native

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
```

Then in your `App.js`

```
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['ViewPagerAndroid']);
```

You can read more about suppressing warnings [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging#warnings)

Comment: If a seperate viewpagerAndroid module is installed, will the code survive after deprecation?